# Google Weather API temperature conversion

Tags: php, xml, weather-api, google-weather-api

Google weather API shows temperature in Fahrenheit.

After watching [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059895/google-weather-api-change-from-f-to-c), I was able to convert temperature from F to C.

However, it shows like `17.222222222222° C - 28.888888888889° C, Clear`. How can i make it only `17° C-28° C`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **The Google weather API was shut down in 2012** -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145820/google-weather-api-gone/35943521

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function toCelsius($deg)
{
  return floor(($deg-32)/1.8);
}
```

You can use [floor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) to return the next lowest integer value by rounding down value if necessary.